# Create a plot, flipping axes while keeping the same scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting some graphs to introduce the concept of mathematical function to highschool students. Right now, I'd like to give them an example of what is NOT a function, by plotting an horizontal parabola:

```
x <- seq(from = -3, to = 3, by = 0.001)
y <- -x^2 + 5

grafico <- ggplot()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y),color="darkred",size=1)+
  theme_light()+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -100, to = 100, by = 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -100, to = 100, by = 1))+
  coord_flip(ylim = c(-1.5,5.5), xlim = c(-3,3),expand = FALSE)

print(grafico)
```

Which outputs the following image:

[image]

This is quite close to what I want, but I would like both axes' scales to match, to keep things simple for the students. For this, I'd tried using coord_equal, but unluckily, it seems to cancel coord_flip's effects:

```
    x <- seq(from = -3, to = 3, by = 0.001)
y <- -x^2 + 5

grafico <- ggplot()+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0)+
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y),color="darkred",size=1)+
  theme_light()+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -100, to = 100, by = 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -100, to = 100, by = 1))+
  coord_flip(ylim = c(-1.5,5.5), xlim = c(-3,3),expand = FALSE)+
  coord_equal()

print(grafico)
```

[image]

My question is:  **Is there a simple way to include coord_flip functionality into coord_equal?**

For example, I know I can get coord_cartesian functionality [by using the parameters *ylim* and *xlim*](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/647).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your use case, it doesn't look like you really *need* to flip the coordinates: you can just reverse the order of inputs for x & y, and use `geom_path()` instead of `geom_line()` to force the plot to follow the order in your inputs.

The ggplot help file states:

> `geom_path()` connects the observations in the order in which they
>   appear in the data. `geom_line()` connects them in order of the
>   variable on the x axis.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_path(mapping = aes(x = y, y = x), color="darkred", size = 1) + # switch x & y here
  theme_light() +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -100, to = 100, by = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -100, to = 100, by = 1)) +
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-1.5, 5.5), ylim = c(-3, 3), expand = FALSE) # switch x & y here
```

[image: plot]